# TP-Link Unable to Reset Default Gateway for Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Recently I got another TP-Link router to extend my home WIFI network. However I set the IP address to 192.168.0.2 and now I can't connect to the Internet.

I reset the router and logged in again to the 192.168.0.1 IP using my mobile data connection, found my network there and then reset the default gateway back to the original 192.168.0.1 IP. After rebooting the router, I found out that the default gateway in the LAN settings have changed back but the default gateway for the Internet in the Status page is still 192.168.0.2, which should be the reason behind the Internet problem.

I'm trying to reset the Internet default gateway back to the original 192.168.0.1 IP. Should I do that and if so how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I got another TP-Link router to extend my home WIFI network

So this is connected to another router.

Connect a LAN port on the TP-Link to a LAN port on the main network.

Set the LAN address to 192.168.0.x (probably not .1) which is a static IP on the main network.

In the LAN section turn DCHP OFF. You want to extend your network.

When this is done, leave the TP-Link hooked up and restart both routers.

You should now have Internet on TP-Link